# Why do I get duplicate YouTube controls in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, youtube

YouTube videos have a duplicate set of controls under the normal controls in Safari.

Safari:
[image: Safari YouTube controls]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox YouTube controls]

MacOS 10.12.5 and Safari 10.1.1.

The only Safari extension I have enabled is 1Password.

What's causing that other set of controls under the normal ones?